# Symfony 2 - Form collection - Label translation

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

I'm trying to translate a label in my twig. 
I have a basic contact form with firstname, lastname, phone, email.
 I have a collection called "BookContact" in which I'm able to add many contacts.
 The user can generate a new contact form by clicking the "add contact" button (jQuery event using prototype as explained here : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html, I'm not working with taks and tafgs but with BookContact and Contact ).

When I display my collection in the twig:

```
{% for contact in form_book_contact.contacts %}
Contact n° {{ num_contact }}
    <div class="row" id="bookcontacts" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form_book_contact.contacts.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               {{ form_widget(contact.firstname) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               {{ form_widget(contact.lastname) }}
            </div>
          ....
 {% endfor %}
```

The inputs look like:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.lastname" name="book_contact[contacts][0][lastname]" id="book_contact_contacts_0_lastname">
```

And my translation file has:

```
 book_contact:
     firstname:            "Prénom"
     lastname:             "Nom"
.....
```

In this case, the translation doesn't work (which is normal because the name of the input is not "firstname" but "0.firsname".
The problem is that I cannot handle the number of the generation of contact forms.
When the user clicks the "add contact" button, the inputs look like: "1.firstname" etc...

How can I handle this kind of translation? How can I manage this number changing in my translation file ?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

As labels are already translated in [the default form layout](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L222), you should only have to set it in your form type.

So if you have a form type:

```
class BookContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
        ;
    }
}
```

Then simply use the `form_label(form.firstName)` in your template and translate them into messages.fr.yml:

```
Firstname: "Prénom" # Do not forget the first uppercased character
Lastname:  "Nom"
```

Or if you prefer using your translation prefix:

```
class BookContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', null, [
                'label' => 'book_contact.firstname',
            ])
            ->add('lastname', null, [
                'label' => 'book_contact.lastname',
             ])
        ;
    }
}
```

And use the following messages.fr.yml:

```
book_contact:
    firstname:            "Prénom"
    lastname:             "Nom"
```

---